# Cassandra IN Clause in a single partition

Tags: cassandra

I googled and found out that in Cassandra having a IN Clause is considered not-so-desirable because of performance considerations.

If I have a table like

```
create table Genre (
   genre_id bigint,
   movie_id bigint,
   primary key (genre_id, movie_id)
);
```

and write query like

```
select * from Genre where genre_id = 1 and movie_id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

is this still considered bad? I feeling is that since I am using a single partition (genre_id) therefore the IN clause should not be considered bad for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Single Partition IN query is considered Good**
Because you tell cassandra which node has your data, So Cassandra just have to query on that node and filter with your in clause.

Try to keep the in clause small, Because all your filtering will be in a single node and the coordinator node will wait for the full result, can result in a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it depends... In general, as long as you keep your list short (eg 10 elements) you are safe.

Adding more elements always produces an increment of the execution time of the query, that will eventually timeout, and an incremented pressure on the coordinator (it will have to store all the results before sending them to the client).

If a typical the record you fetch with a single value in the IN clause is big enough (eg you get a long BLOB), even a two items IN clause query could kill your performances.